# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatHC.setAlpha(ViewCompatHC.java:101)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-studio

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatHC.setAlpha(ViewCompatHC.java:101)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$HCViewCompatImpl.setAlpha(ViewCompat.java:811)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setAlpha(ViewCompat.java:1978)
            at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:93)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my onCreate block where the error is being thrown from:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_header_height);
   mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
   mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

   mHeaderPicture = (KenSupportView) findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
   mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.default_bg_1, R.drawable.default_bg_2);
   mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
   mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);

   mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

   mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);

   mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

   mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
   mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
   mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.actionbar_title));
   mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff);

   ViewCompat.setAlpha(getActionBarIconView(), 0f); // error here

   getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
}
```

and the method block for `getActionBarIconView()`:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {

   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
       return (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
   }

   return (ImageView)findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home);
  }
```

build.gradle:

```
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 21
     buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.myapp"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 20
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             runProguard false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }
```

I'm not sure why it is throwing a null pointer exception when R.id.home resolves to integer 16908332 when I log the error. I've also ensured that setContentView comes first.

Could anyone kindly help?

Comment: So when is `getActionBarIconView()` returning `null`? What's your theme? Are you using `Activity` or something like `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: I am using ActionBarActivity, and Theme.AppCompat. getActionBarIconView() shouldn't be returning null.

Comment: Ok i reran the code to see if 'getActionBarIconView()' returned null. Indeed it did, but I've no idea why.

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing your issue?  I'm experiencing the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The Material Design Action Bar has changed dramatically in [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and is now based on the concept of a Toolbar:

> In this release, Android introduces a new [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) widget. This is a generalization of the Action Bar pattern that gives you much more control and flexibility. Toolbar is a view in your hierarchy just like any other, making it easier to interleave with the rest of your views, animate it, and react to scroll events. You can also set it as your Activity’s action bar, meaning that your standard options menu actions will be display within it.

This also means that AppCompat no longer uses the system provided Action Bar on any API level: it always creates a custom Toolbar which is set as the Action Bar. Per the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) documentation:

> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

By default, the Toolbar (and hence, any Action Bar when using AppCompat) does **not** have any application icon, hence why `getActionBarIconView()` returns null.

Comment: how do I then find the equivalent of android.R.id.home for Toolbar?

Comment: What are you expecting `android.R.id.home` equivalent to point to? The optional navigation button? The optional logo? There is no direct equivalent (nor do any of the views have ids) so you'll have to explain *why* you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: I want it to point to the optional logo so that I can perform some transformation to the icon.